# How to disable / enable futon in couchdb?

Tags: couchdb

I have a couchdb, running in a non-standard port, which is giving me the following:

```
http://localhost:59876/_utils

{"error":"illegal_database_name","reason":"Only lowercase characters (a-z), digits (0-9), and any of the characters _, $, (, ), +, -, and / are allowed. Must begin with a letter."}
```

Which shows me that futon is disabled. Is there any setting in the config file which would allow me to enable (and disable) futon?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That is not normal. I wonder if you have any config file issue. There should be a configuration entry like this.

```
[httpd_global_handlers]
_utils = {couch_httpd_misc_handlers, handle_utils_dir_req, "/usr/local/share/couchdb/www"}
```

That is what tells CouchDB that `_utils` is an ok query and it sill serve Futon.